# How to remove the borders around the TabPane Tabs wrapper

Tags: css, javafx

How can I go about removing the borders around the TabPane Tabs wrapper (The dark gray border below)?

[image: TabPane Tabs Wrapper]

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
.tab-pane *.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-effect: innershadow(two-pass-box , transparent , 0, 0.0 , 0 , 0);
}
```